# Firefox does not record the audio from the navigator.getMediaStream if tab is left idle for sometime

Tags: firefox, audio, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I have implemented an audio recording functionality using `navigator.getMediaStream`, it is working fine in chrome and firefox but if tab is left idle for sometime then firefox does not capture audio, it record without sound.

Comment: I guess you can workaround that bug by forcing the tab to not be put in idle, which can be done by starting a Web Audio Context (`const ctx = new AudioContext(); const silence = ctx.createGain(); silence.gain.value = 0; silence.connect(ctx.destination); const osc = ctx.createOscillator(); osc.connect(silence); osc.start(0)` should be enough), but I lack time to test it myself.

Comment: FWIW, I tried reproducing quickly the issue but after 2mins of recording with the tab in the background it still did work correctly on my FF 93.0 on macOS. How long did you wait before it happens for you?